# zoom into the data of particular type

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a plot displaying the relative amount for a given case. In the following example, for a given `val`, the relative amount of `depth`.

Now I would like to show the contribution for the `depth` according to `Species` to corelate with `val`.
How could I show this information. For example in the plot for `val` `2.5-3` what would be the distribution of `Species` in each of the corresponding `depth`.

```
library(dplyr)

# cut sepal length and sepal width

iris$depth <-cut(iris$Sepal.Length,
                    breaks = c(4,5,6,7,8))

iris$val <- cut(iris$Sepal.Width,
                breaks = c(1.9,2.5,3,3.5,4,6))

iris_data <- iris %>% 
  group_by(val, depth) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  mutate(perc = count/sum(count))


library(ggplot2)
a<-ggplot(iris_data, 
                aes(x = factor(val), y = perc, 
                    fill = factor(depth))) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.5)
a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if I understood your question correctly, but this might help:

Keep Species as variable (summarise also by Species) and use it as facetting variable.

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris %>%
  mutate(depth = cut(iris$Sepal.Length, breaks = c(4,5,6,7,8)),
         val  = cut(iris$Sepal.Width,breaks = c(1.9,2.5,3,3.5,4,6))
         ) %>%
  group_by(Species, val, depth) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  mutate(perc = count/sum(count)) %>%


ggplot(aes(x = factor(val), y = perc, 
              fill = factor(depth))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.5) +
  facet_wrap(~Species)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Species', 'val'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>